# how to use uniswap with hardhat?

Tags: hardhat, uniswap

I am try to using uniswap in hardhat test:

```
it("should getAmountsOut for Token", async function () {
    const uniswapRouterAddress = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";
    const wethAddress = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
    const usdcAddress = "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48";

    const uniswapRouter = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("IUniswapV2Router02", uniswapRouterAddress);
    const amountsOut = await uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut(1, [wethAddress, usdcAddress]);
});
```

but error:

```
TypeError: uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut is not a function
```

Comment: Are you testing on a forked nework?

Comment: yes @donoso.eth

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `IUniswapV2Router02` interface (`IUniswapV2Router02.sol`) in your project or you can create it as follow:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IUniswapV2Router02 {
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path)
        external
        view
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}
```